# Debugging Azure - An error occurred loading a configuration file

Tags: debugging, azure

I can debug my application fine but if I debug the Azure project, it loads the compute and storage emulators, loads the browser and goes to 127.0.0.1:81 and then I get the error:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Access to the path 'C:\Users\Projects\Web\views\web.config' is denied.

I am using November 2011 Azure SDK and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 in admin mode with IIS7.

If I publish the website to Azure then everything works fine, it's just a debugging issue.

**EDIT**

Ah, it needs to be running under C:\inetpub\wwwroot to debug the Azure project. How can I get it to work outside of that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging the web project I was using Cassini. When debugging Azure it uses IIS.

1. I had to add the user account of **NETWORK SERVICE** to my solution files.
2. To access the local database when debugging Azure locally, the database needs the user **NETWORK SERVICE** adding to it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure does not change anything with respect your ASP.NET configuration instead it just use the same ASP.NET application and configuration to run your application in compute emulator. So when you run your application in compute emulator the whole ASP.NET project runs  from the same folder where your application was and in IIS you can verify as the image below:

[image]

I am very much suspecting that by any reason the folder/file is read only that's why web.config is not accessible. I believe you should investigate this problem from your drive/files security and accessing point not from ASP.NET/Azure perspective because I dont see any error over there..

Answer (score 0):

If you have source control, I think there is sometimes an error if the web.config file has the readonly attribute set on it in the file system. I'd check there first.